# Why does grid row change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crud

I have a asp.net page with a grid and, above the grid, fields showing the contents of the highlighted row and some buttons (edit, add, delete, etc...).
If the user clicks the edit button then it enables the fields for editing.
However, after enabling the fields the grid is then refreshed or something and the first row is then highlighted and the fields on the screen changes. Why? How do I stop this?

Code is below:

```
        protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        updatetype = "Edit";
    }

        protected void ChangeButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAdd.Enabled = !btnAdd.Enabled;
        btnCopy.Enabled = !btnCopy.Enabled;
        btnEdit.Enabled = !btnEdit.Enabled;
        btnDelete.Enabled = !btnDelete.Enabled;
        btnCancel.Enabled = !btnCancel.Enabled;
        btnSave.Enabled = !btnSave.Enabled;
        btnClose.Enabled = !btnClose.Enabled;
        btnSearchCredits.Enabled = !btnSearchCredits.Enabled;
        btnClearCredits.Enabled = !btnClearCredits.Enabled;
    }

               protected void ChangeFields(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSrchCredible_ID.Enabled = !txtSrchCredible_ID.Enabled;
        txtSrchADP_ID.Enabled = !txtSrchADP_ID.Enabled;
        txtSrchStart_Date.Enabled = !txtSrchStart_Date.Enabled;
        txtSrchEnd_Date.Enabled = !txtSrchEnd_Date.Enabled;
        txtCredible_ID.Enabled = !txtCredible_ID.Enabled;
        txtADP_ID.Enabled = !txtADP_ID.Enabled;
        txtEmployee_ID.Enabled = !txtEmployee_ID.Enabled;
        txtStart_Date.Enabled = !txtStart_Date.Enabled;
        txtEnd_Date.Enabled = !txtEnd_Date.Enabled;
        txtReason.Enabled = !txtReason.Enabled;
        txtUnits.Enabled = !txtUnits.Enabled;
        txtPercentage.Enabled = !txtPercentage.Enabled;
        txtOther.Enabled = !txtOther.Enabled;
    }
```

Comment: Comment out the two "Change" methods at top of code and see what happens.

Comment: I suspect you are re-loading the grid each time in the page load event. You need to ONLY load the data the first time in the page load event with if(!IsPostBack) {your grid load code goes here}. Remember, page load event fires each and every time  - for all button and code behind events. If you re-load (re-bind) the GV, the you going to lose your index and settings to the GV.

Comment: Thank you Albert! that was it!